# How do I use C# to edit text fields in a website?

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone

I am a beginner windows phone developer and I want to go to a url, log in to the website using string values (for the username and password) and retrieve data on the next web page. Would I use a webClient/WebBrowser for this? I don't really understand how I should go about 'editing' the text fields on the web page, to fill in my user name and password and whatnot.

Once I have managed to log in to this website, there are a couple pieces of data that i want to be shown in my application that are text values. How can I go about doing this? All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should look at it in terms of what data needs to be POSTed to the page, instead of what form fields need to be manipulated.  This will create a very fragile link between your application and the page, but if you use something like the chrome inspector to inspect the request after you hit the submit button, you can see what sort of parameters you should post to the page.  And something like the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse objects should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3):

In line with my comment, I created a method that takes in a cookiejar (this allows for a persistent session across requests) a uri, and parameters and does a post to the URI.

```
    private static string PerformPostRequest(string uri, CookieContainer cookieJar, string parameters)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;


        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
        Stream os = null;


        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;  
        os = request.GetRequestStream();
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        if (os != null)
        {
            os.Close();
        }


        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }
```

After posting the log in information that you need to the login page, you could then perform a get request on the next page, and parse the data there.

```
    private static string PerformGetRequest(string uri, CookieContainer cookieJar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;


        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! When you say inspect "it" after submitting, what will I be looking at? I inspected the fields before typing and know their id's but how do I know what parameters to pass to the encoder? Also why is this code so unbelievably complicated?! I've never dealt with web development before and don't understand 90% of the stuff you wrote. Should I look into the subject somewhere else before trying to do this? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Stefan's answer is pretty good.  I'll add the conceptual piece I think is missing.

Text fields or more commonly referred to as HTML Form and Input Tags/Elements, are only a visual representation required for humans to populate using keyboard, mouse and javascript events.  These tags are not required to be edited in a web browser at all.  Disregarding Ajax, a web browse simple takes the values and formats them into a request (typically get or post) and sends that request to a http server.  With AJAX the request has a few more required parameters.

All that is really needed on your end is a fairly easy two step process. First create a request that contains the required values and secondly send that request to the http server.  This is a very general idea of what is actually needed.  There are some caveats that can make this more difficult depending on the website in question (typically [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) is used to prevent this type of automation on some from requests, for example).

If you have control over the website or can request additional functionality, I would not use HTML and instead highly recommend using a RESTful or similar API for your application to access.  This would make the work involved in your application less complicated.

Comment: This is a good overview of what you will need to do in your application to get at the data that you need.  I totally agree, accessing this data through pretty much ANYTHING other than the HTTP web requests will give you a far more stable connection.